# scheduler timelineDay long period snaps events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible to prevent the timelineDay view of snapping resources to a full day (see image), as you can see the start/end time aren't exactly on day start/end but for some reason it gets snapped. (see the red line, it should end at 13:43)

[image: Resource snapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the scheduler so I am not sure about this but have you looked into the [slotDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/slotDuration/) and [snapDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/snapDuration/). Try setting them to a lower value. I believe the slotDuration default value is 30 minutes, it looks like you may need to set it to 1 minute if possible.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed resolved the issue, it automatically calculated the slotDuration to be a 24 hour duration

Comment: Glad I could help.